# Display image From database to jsp page

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, blob

I got this Error each time when I run the page:

> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke GRAVE: Servlet.service() >for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/hamza] threw exception [Impossible de >compiler la classe pour la JSP] with root cause
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Page directive: invalid value for import

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" %>
  <%@ page language="java" %>
    <%@ page session="true" %>
      <%@ page import="java.sql.*,java.io.*" %>
        <% String login=(String)session.getAttribute( "login"); login=( session.getAttribute( "login")==null) ? "Null" : (String)session.getAttribute( "login"); %>

          <% Blob photo=n ull; byte[ ] imgData=n ull ; Statement stmt=n ull; ResultSet rs=n ull; Connection theConnection=null ; try { Class.forName( "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:mysql://localhost/pfe", "root", ""); stmt=t heConnection.createStatement();
          rs=s tmt.executeQuery( "select photo from register where login = '"+login+ "'"); if (rs.next()) { photo=r s.getBlob(1); imgData=p hoto.getBytes(1,(int)photo.length()); } else { out.println( "Display Blob Example"); out.println(
          "image not found for given login"); return; } // display the image response.setContentType( "photo/png"); OutputStream o=r esponse.getOutputStream(); o.write(imgData); o.flush(); o.close(); } catch (Exception e) { out.println( "Unable To Display image"); out.println(
          "Image Display Error=" + e.getMessage()); return;} finally { try { rs.close(); stmt.close(); theConnection.close(); } catch (SQLException e) { e.printStackTrace(); } } %>
```

Comment: StandardWrapperValve.invoke is a function, not an error. Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/hamza] threw exception [An exception occurred processing JSP page /user/profile/Display.jsp at line 48

45: 
46:                         try {
47: 
48:                         rs.close();
49: 
50:                         stmt.close();
51:

Comment: And when i delete Rs.close(); it show me stmt.close() and conn.close() ;